# HOW TO "Arbitrary" format items in list/dict/etc. EX: change 4th character in every string in list

Tags: python, formatting

first of all i want to mention that there might not be any real life applications for this simple script i created, but i did it because I'm learning and I couldn't find anything similar here in SO. I wanted to know what could be done to "arbitrarily" change characters in an iterable like a list.

Sure `tile()` is a handy tool I learned relatively quick, but then I got to think what if, just for kicks, i wanted to format (upper case) the last character instead? or the third, the middle one,etc. What about lower case? Replacing specific characters with others?

Like I said this is surely not perfect but could give away some food for thought to other noobs like myself. Plus I think this can be modified in hundreds of ways to achieve all kinds of different formatting.

How about helping me improve what I just did? how about making it more lean and mean? checking for style, methods, efficiency, etc...

Here it goes:

```
words = ['house', 'flower', 'tree']  #string list

counter = 0                          #counter to iterate over the items in list
chars = 4                            #character position in string (0,1,2...)

for counter in range (0,len(words)): 
    while counter < len(words):
        z = list(words[counter])     # z is a temp list created to slice words
        if len(z) > chars:           # to compare char position and z length
            upper = [k.upper() for k in z[chars]] # string formatting EX: uppercase
            z[chars] = upper [0]     # replace formatted character with original
            words[counter] = ("".join(z)) # convert and replace temp list back into original word str list
            counter +=1
        else:
            break

print (words)

['housE', 'flowEr', 'tree']
```

Comment: May be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please fix the indentation so it's runnable, and get rid of all of the extra blank lines, if you want people to read your code.

Comment: @abarnet my bad, is it better now? What do you mean by "extra blank lines?

Comment: You have a blank line after almost, but not quite, every single line of code. There is no reason for them, and they make it much harder to read your code.

Comment: I eliminated a few blank lines, at least for the looping should be better now. It's interesting though how the easiness or hardness to read might be perceptual according to each person's knowledge degree of , in this case Python. For a beginner like myself, for example, without the blank lines is harder to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat of a combination of both (so +1 to both of them :) ). The main function accepts a list, an arbitrary function and the character to act on:

```
In [47]: def RandomAlter(l, func, char):
    return [''.join([func(w[x]) if x == char else w[x] for x in xrange(len(w))]) for w in l]
   ....:

In [48]: RandomAlter(words, str.upper, 4)
Out[48]: ['housE', 'flowEr', 'tree']

In [49]: RandomAlter([str.upper(w) for w in words], str.lower, 2)
Out[49]: ['HOuSE', 'FLoWER', 'TReE']

In [50]: RandomAlter(words, lambda x: '_', 4)
Out[50]: ['hous_', 'flow_r', 'tree']
```

The function `RandomAlter` can be rewritten as this, which may make it a bit more clear (it takes advantage of a feature called [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to reduce the lines of code needed).

```
def RandomAlter(l, func, char):
    # For each word in our list
    main_list = []
    for w in l:
        # Create a container that is going to hold our new 'word'
        new_word = []
        # Iterate over a range that is equal to the number of chars in the word
        # xrange is a more memory efficient 'range' - same behavior
        for x in xrange(len(w)):
            # If the current position is the character we want to modify
            if x == char:
                # Apply the function to the character and append to our 'word'
                # This is a cool Python feature - you can pass around functions
                # just like any other variable
                new_word.append(func(w[x]))
            else:
                # Just append the normal letter
                new_word.append(w[x])

        # Now we append the 'word' to our main_list. However since the 'word' is
        # a list of letters, we need to 'join' them together to form a string
        main_list.append(''.join(new_word))

    # Now just return the main_list, which will be a list of altered words
    return main_list
```

Comment: maaaany things i don't know or understand yet here...have to look into this for a while...for starters what are 47, 48, 49....in, out?!?!

Comment: @Newbie Ha, my apologies - let me update it so it is a bit more useful :) The '47' / '48' stuff is from an interpreter called IPython - similar to the standard interpreter (where you can type in things interactively and see how they work out), but with additional features.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i went over the stuff and i like it, very useful, functions and comprehensions are two subjects i need to get deeper into. One note: i don't think there is xrange in python 3.3 any longer, but i read that the changes made to range make it behave as did xrange aka it doesn't create a list unlesst it's told so. Cheers.

Comment: @Newbie Exactly right - no more `xrange` (and sorry, it looks like you may be using Python 3 - I should have written it with respect to that). In any case, functions and comprehensions are indeed incredibly useful. In my opinion, understanding how to build lists/dicts/etc. using standard `for` loops first is good because you can then better understand/appreciate what comprehensions do. All-in-all, in my opinion you're off to a great start - good luck with everything!

Answer (score 2):

There's much better Pythonistas than me, but here's one attempt:

```
[''.join(
      [a[x].upper() if x == chars else a[x]
          for x in xrange(0,len(a))]
    )
    for a in words]
```

Also, we're talking about the programmer's 4th, right? What everyone else calls 5th, yes?

Comment: should i replace your function with what in mine?

Comment: what do you mean by 4th or 5th?? can't say for sure since i can't call myself a programmer yet! hehe

Comment: @Newbie: Programmers usually count from zero: so E in "housE" is fourth letter. h=0, o=1, u=2, s=3, E=4. Most other people count from 1: h=1, o=2, u=3, s=4, E=5.

Comment: @Newbie: As for how to use it, it's just an expression. It expects to have variables `words` and `chars` defined, and will return an array. You can print it, or assign it to a variable, or do anything else with it. For example, `new_words = [ ... ]`. If you want it in the function form, look at the improved version by RocketDonkey.

Comment: thanx!! i just went over your solution and i have to say i like it, mainly because it's in the range of my "comprehension"...

Answer (score 2):

I think the general case of what you're talking about is a method that, given a string and an index, returns that string, with the indexed character transformed according to some rule.

```
def transform_string(strng, index, transform):
    lst = list(strng)
    if index < len(lst):
        lst[index] = transform(lst[index])
    return ''.join(lst)


words = ['house', 'flower', 'tree']
output = [transform_string(word, 4, str.upper) for word in words]
```

To make it even more abstract, you could have a factory that returns a method, like so:

```
def transformation_factory(index, transform):
    def inner(word):
        lst = list(word)
        if index < len(lst):
            lst[index] = transform(lst[index])
    return inner
transform = transformation_factory(4, lambda x: x.upper())
output = map(transform, words)
```

Comment: I like it!! it gets into function definition which is something i have to head my head around, therefore is something that gives me plenty to think about. p.s. there is just a tiny typo in line 4. should be lst not list. Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

What I wrote probably isn't a 'pure' example of the Factory pattern. In essence, a Factory is something that abstracts away the process of creating something. So the transformation_factory version is more abstract, and can be used to create a function with arbitrary transformations on characters with arbitrary indices.

Also, you should really select an answer. Doesn't have to be mine.

Comment: i can't select an answer because i don't know which one should i choose. I was actually hoping to select the one with the most "up ticks" but so far it's a tie. Not a very polular post i guess.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments on your code:

```
for counter in range (0,len(words)):     
while counter < len(words):
```

This won't compile unless you indent the `while` loop under the `for` loop. And, if you do that, the inner loop will completely screw up the loop counter for the outer loop. And finally, you almost never want to maintain an explicit loop counter in Python. You probably want this:

```
for counter, word in enumerate(words):
```

Next:

```
z = list(words[counter])     # z is a temp list created to slice words
```

You can already slice strings, in exactly the same way you slice lists, so this is unnecessary.

Next:

```
    upper = [k.upper() for k in z[chars]] # string formatting EX: uppercase
```

This is a bad name for the variable, since there's a function with the exact same name—which you're calling on the same line.

Meanwhile, the way you defined things, `z[chars]` is a character, a copy of `words[4]`. You can iterate over a single character in Python, because each character is itself a string. but it's generally pointless—`[k.upper() for k in z[chars]]` is the same thing as `[z[chars].upper()]`.

```
    z[chars] = upper [0]     # replace formatted character with original
```

So you only wanted the list of 1 character to get the first character out of it… why make it a list in the first place? Just replace the last two lines with `z[chars] = z[chars].upper()`.

```
else:
    break
```

This is going to stop on the first string shorter than length 4, rather than just skip strings shorter than length 4, which is what it seems like you want. The way to say that is `continue`, not `break`. Or, better, just fall off the end of the list. In some cases, it's hard to write things without a `continue`, but in this case, it's easy—it's already at the end of the loop, and in fact it's inside an `else:` that has nothing else in it, so just remove both lines.

It's hard to tell with `upper` that your loops are wrong, because if you accidentally call `upper` twice, it looks the same as if you called it once. Change the `upper` to `chr(ord(k)+1)`, which replaces any letter with the next letter. Then try it with:

```
words = ['house', 'flower', 'tree', 'a', 'abcdefgh']
```

You'll notice that, e.g., you get `'flowgr'` instead of `'flowfr'`.

You may also want to add a variable that counts up the number of times you run through the inner loop. It should only be `len(words)` times, but it's actually `len(words) * len(words)` if you have no short words, or `len(words) * len(<up to the first short word>)` if you have any. You're making the computer do a whole lot of extra work—if you have 1000 words, it has to do 1000000 loops instead of 1000. In technical terms, your algorithm is O(N^2), even though it only needs to be O(N).

Putting it all together:

```
words = ['house', 'flower', 'tree', 'a', 'abcdefgh']  #string list
chars = 4                            #character position in string (0,1,2...)

for counter, word in enumerate(words): 
    if len(word) > chars:           # to compare char position and z length
        z = list(word)
        z[chars] = chr(ord(z[chars]+1) # replace character with next character
        words[counter] = "".join(z)    # convert and replace temp list back into original word str list

print (words)
```

That does the same thing as your original code (except using "next character" instead of "uppercase character"), without the bugs, with much less work for the computer, and much easier to read.

Comment: the indentation problem was a paste problem. What do you mean "screw up"_? i have run it with proper indentation and runs fine.

Comment: what do you mean by explicit counter?

Comment: what do you mean is going to stop on strings shorter than 4? i just tested with char = 4 and included a string of 3. and i worked fine? it skips strings of length > char and goes to the next string.

Comment: By "screw up", I mean that you're using the same variable name for both loops, so you cannot access the outer counter. You're repeating the loop `len(words)` times, each time looping `len(words)` times, which you almost certainly don't want here—but if you did, you'd probably want to do something with the pair of counters, and you've given yourself no way to do so. And by "explicit counter" I mean a loop like `i = 0; while i < 10: … i += 1` instead of `for i in range(10):`.

Comment: @Newbie: It does not skip strings, it breaks out of the loop and skips that string _and all strings after it_. Read the docs on `continue` and `break` to see the difference. The difference is harder to spot because you have an outer loop that does the same thing as the inner loop, which makes everything more confusing.

Comment: mhhh i tried making the changes you suggested with no results. could you maybe paste you complete proposal? did you test it? I looking forward seeing your changes in action :-)

Comment: Again, you have an outer loop that does the same thing as the inner loop, so it's harder to tell that you're breaking out of the inner loop. If you change the operation from `k.upper()` to something that makes it easier to tell how many times it's been called (e.g., `chr(ord(k)+1)`), you'll see that it gets called twice on every second word, except those that come after the first short word.

Comment: Hi, in if len(z) > chars: "z" isn't defined yet so what i did is replace it with if len(counter) > chars: and then i included a counter+= 1 at the bottom. What do you think?

Comment: @Newbie: Why would you add a `counter += 1` are the bottom? It already counts up each time through the loop. Did you look at what the values are (e.g., by adding a `print` statement)? Also, given that `counter` is a number, what do you expect `len(counter)` to return? You're trying to get the length of the word, right? So, do `len(word)`. Debugging doesn't mean randomly changing things until the compiler stops complaining; you need to understand what the code is trying to do before you can fix it.

Comment: my bad, i actually wrote it wrong here and not in my code  what i meant was: if len(words[counter]), that's why it worked when i run it. Not saying was a good solution, just that i mistyped in the post. Thanks

Comment: you right about the debugging stuff, hopefully i'll get there. I'm the first to feel uncomfortable not knowing what is actually happening. One of the reasons i post here.